# Retrieving data about comments and likes

Tags: javascript, rest-api

What's the easiest way to fetch the number of comments and the number of likes a post has?

I don't see any usefull field when fetching a post (with a request like https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=2018-07-21T15:05:44.000Z)

I'm currently using javascript issuing direct requests with axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the comments by checking:

```
https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=150
```

Where `post=150`, is the ID of the post.

I don't really know what do you mean by `likes`, but there are not `likes` WordPressPres natively.

Comment: on WordPress.com there is the possibility to click a button to like a post, and it is documented here how to get data about this https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/likes/. Some WordPress sites have likes, maybe they add them through the JetPack plugin?